# Issue with multiple criteria in bindingsource.filter

Tags: c#, filter, bindingsource

I am trying to filter  a binding source based on 2 comboboxes.  I have one of comboboxes filter just fine.  The second has me stumped as it uses the first combobox and then the second based on a switch statement:

```
    private void comboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender,
    System.EventArgs e)
    {
        string sItem;
        sItem = comboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString();

        switch (sItem)
        {
            case "Banks":
                propertyInformationBindingSource.Filter = ("ClientKey ='" + comboBox1.SelectedValue + "'" And "Search = -1");
                break;
            case "Exam":
                propertyInformationBindingSource.Filter = ("ClientKey ='" + comboBox1.SelectedValue + "'") And ("Exam = -1");
                break;
            case "Search Finished":
                propertyInformationBindingSource.Filter = ("ClientKey ='" + comboBox1.SelectedValue + "'") And ("Finished = -1;
                break;
            case "All":
                propertyInformationBindingSource.Filter = "ClientKey ='" + comboBox1.SelectedValue + "'";
                break;


        }
    }
```

I am having issues with the value after the AND in which it claims is wrong.  Any help would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there were some string concatenation issues and you were missing the closing parenthesis around `Finisher = -1`.

Try

```
 switch (sItem)
        {
            case "Banks":
                propertyInformationBindingSource.Filter = ("ClientKey ='" + comboBox1.SelectedValue + "' And Search = -1");
                break;
            case "Exam":
                propertyInformationBindingSource.Filter = ("ClientKey ='" + comboBox1.SelectedValue + "' And Exam = -1");
                break;
            case "Search Finished":
                propertyInformationBindingSource.Filter = ("ClientKey ='" + comboBox1.SelectedValue + "' And Finished = -1");
                break;
            case "All":
                propertyInformationBindingSource.Filter = "ClientKey ='" + comboBox1.SelectedValue + "'";
                break;


        }
```

Note if you have too much string concatenation going on, it's best that you use `string.Format()`. It improves readability and is more efficient that concatenation. As an example, you first case would look like this

```
propertyInformationBindingSource.Filter = 
      string.Format("ClientKey ='{0}' And Search = -1", comboBox1.SelectedValue);
```

Comment: @Bala R the syntax seems to be correct but I am still not getting the desired results.  When using combobox2 it always comes back with no records.

Comment: @Korrowan if you put a break-point at the end of the switch block, what does `propertyInformationBindingSource.Filter` look like?

Comment: @Bala R for Case "Banks"  it is "ClientKey ='3' And Search = -1"

Comment: What's the datatype of ClientKey? if it's not a string maybe you can skip the single quotes. Otherwise, the Filter expression looks good to me.

Comment: @Bala R I took the single quotes out.  It seems to work ONLY for Banks...everything else is ignored.

Comment: You did take out the single quotes in all cases of your switch, right?

Comment: @Bala R Yes I took them all out.  I put break points at every 'break' and the only one that is ever executed is 'banks'.  Outside of that problem it functions!

Comment: Can you check what's in `sItem = comboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString();` ?

Comment: @Bala R nevermind I made a mistake in my combo box!  Thanks a ton for your help!